# Is there a difference between "wegen" and "aufgrund?"

Tags: meaning

I am under the impression that both "wegen" and "aufgrund" mean "because of." Is there any difference in their meaning or usage?

Comment: Today is no real difference between "wegen" and "aufgrund" in German language. Also "weil" is used (we mainly use "weil"). Still "aufgrund" is mostly used in 'higher' explanations like in science or politics.

Answer (score 5):

Both **wegen**+Genitiv and **aufgrund**+Genitiv are prepositions with that very same meaning *because of*. The latter is made from the words *auf Grund*. There is also an adverb *aufgrund*, which takes the preposition *von*+Dativ.

It's common to use *wegen* as an answer to questions leaded by *weswegen* and *weshalb*. It's an everyday word.

*Aufgrund* in contrary sounds a bit stilted. Don't use it in speech, it sounds as if you were giving an official statement.

Comment: I'd simply label "aufgrund" as a formal word used in written German or in speeches; for me, it doesn't have stilted connotations per se. Might be a subjective perception on my side.

Comment: "aufgrund" is neither formal nor stilted. Its just a word thats more often used in educated circles and less so in others. If you want to sound professional, "aufgrund" is better than "wegen" in *almost* every case.